# Expected value of functions of order statistics

Tags: probability, order-statistics

Let $F$ be a CDF over $[\underline{y},\bar{y}]$ and $g(\cdot)$ is some strictly increasing function. I know the following has at least one solution. 
\begin{equation}
2F(y)\int_{\underline{y}}^{y}g(x)\frac{dF(x)}{F(y)}=\int_{\underline{y}}^{y}g(x)\frac{dF(x)^2}{F(y)^2}\end{equation}
Can we guarantee that the solution is unique? (assume $g(\underline{y})>0$)

Comment: why do you have $F(y)$ both at the numerator and in denominator at the left side?

Comment: Oh sure. Just left it that way to leave the conditional densities the same. No other reason.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is not unique, in general. just take $F$ to be uniform on $[0,1]$. Write the equation as $$h(y)=f(y)-g(y)$$

The second derivative of $h$ must be strictly positive or negative in order to guarantee the uniqueness. One gets however (for $\int xdx^2$, i had $dx^2=dy$, $x=\sqrt{y}$)

$$h(y)=(3/2)y^5-y^{3/2}-(3/2)y^2c^3+c^{3/2}$$
and
$$h^{''}(y;c)=30y^3-(3/4)y^{-1/2}-3c^3$$

Since $c=0$, because $F$ is uniform on $[0,1]$, we have 
$$h^{''}(y)=30y^3-(3/4)y^{-1/2}$$
which is neither positive nor negative for all $y$.

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot+30x%5E3-(3%2F4)x%5E(-1%2F2)++from+0+to+0.5

Comment: The second derivative condition is only sufficient, not necessary. So the fact that the first derivative is not monotone, i.e. the second derivative is not single signed, is not enough to show that solution is not unique.

Comment: In this case it doesnt matter, as $h$ has two roots one at $0$ and the other near $y=0.9$, yet this is the simplest case with a uniform distribution.

Comment: fair enough. How about solutions in the interior of the support? (I don't really care about the ends).

Comment: @user425638 I am unable to see a structure here to prove, if it is at all true, that there is a single root in $(0,1)$. I would consider $g(x)=f_1(x)/f_0(x)$ and $dF(x)/dx=f_0(x)$. One such example for $f_0$ and $f_1$ is mean shifted Gaussian densities. One can check for different values of $\mu_0, mu_1$ and $\sigma$.

Comment: Thanks! Thank you for taking time to look at this.

Comment: @user425638 you are welcome